# Send email with embedding binary image in php

Tags: php, image, symfony, binary, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send email with images, but only have the binary code in my server.
Any idea how to do it?

Now I'm sending the html like this (in base 64 encoded):

```
<img src="data:image/png; base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANIAAANBCAYAAAC ..." />
```

I'm using the SwiftMailer library from Symfony2 to send the emails.

A full example code (with cuts in the binary code):

```
//params
$subject = "Demo e-mail";
$body = "<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src='data:image/png; base64, iVBORw0KGgo...zIIAAAAASUVORK5CYII='>
            </td>
            <td style='padding-left:20px'>
                <div>
                    <h3>Product name</h3>
                    <h4>Code 3089</h4>
                    <p>14.70 $</p>
                </div>
              </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </html>";
$name = "Client name";
$email = "clientmail@domain.com";
$from_address = "mail@domain.com";
$from_name = "App Name";

//SwiftMessag eobject 
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom(array($from_address => $from_name))
        ->setTo(array($email => $name))
        ->setBody($body, 'text/html');

//send email
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Comment: I just saw that `data:` is duplicated. Can you try with only one `data:`?

Comment: Ok, issue from copy/paste, but in the project is not duplicated.That's not the problem.

Comment: How do you send this image to Swiftmailer? Please show the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I embedded an image in an email with this code:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();

$body = '<html><head></head><body>'.
    '<p><img src="'.$message->embed(\Swift_Image::fromPath(
        \Swift_Attachment::fromPath([full path to you image]
    )
    ->setDisposition('inline'))).'" alt="Image" /></p>'.
    '</body></html>'
;

$message
    ->setSubject('Subject')
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->setTo($to)
    ->setBody(
        $body,
        'text/html'
    )
;

$this->mailer->send($message);
```

Replace `[full path to you image]` with a path to your image, for example `dirname(__FILE__).'/../images/image.png'`.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to send an image with absolute path.

But, my question was if I can send the image binary, because the image file not in my server, and these server only returns me the binary code.

Is there any way to do?

Comment: @jpintor I'm sorry it doesn't help you. Can you try to save the binary code on your server to a PNG file, then to embed this image?

Comment: Yes, I could save the image in a file, but i wanted avoid it.

However, I will try to do it and delete the file later.